# Loop through rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have this if statemtns, if i want it to loop through every row that has a value in column("A2:A50") how can i do that? I tried a lot but have not figured out how to do it. My code for the if statemtens are these,

```
 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:D50")) = 0 Then
   Error 1001
ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B50")) > 0 And WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C50")) > 0 Then
   Error 1001
End If
```

The if statements works and they do what I want to but they do not loop as I wish, what i want it to do is the following:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A50")) > 50 Then
Do the if statements above and loop.
```

Comment: you mean you want check the value from A2 to A50?

Answer (score 0):

I've re edit that, could you test it?

```
Sub loopXER()

'Define variables
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim cell3 As Range


'Set the range to use
Set rng = Range("A2:A50")
Set rng2 = Range("B2:D50")
Set rng3 = Range("B2:B50")
Set rng4 = Range("C2:C50")


'Iterate through each cell in range
For Each cell In rng
'If cell is empty or it's value is over 50, go to if's defined by OP, else go to next cell
    If IsEmpty(cell) Or cell.Value > 50 Then
         For Each cell1 In rng2
            If IsEmpty(cell1) Or cell1.Value = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Error 1001"
            End If
         Next cell1

         For Each cell2 In rng3
            If cell2.Value > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Error 1001"
            End If
         Next cell2

         For Each cell3 In rng4
            If cell3.Value > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Error 1001"
            End If
         Next cell3

    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but still if row 2 is not empty but range B2:D50 is empty it doesnt give an error. It doesnt loop

Comment: Ah ok I got it. Since you said the if statements worked I thought you didnt need the cell verification. I will try to change it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim data As Range
  Dim myCell As Range

  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A50")  

  'If *any* cell has a value in this range (adjust as required)
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then

    'Capture cells with values and formulae
    Set data = Union(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23), _
                     rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23))

    data.Select

    For Each myCell In data

      Debug.Print myCell.Address

    Next

  End If
```